# Converting JSON in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to convert this

```
[ { "_id": "57760ecef5e7478c1e46b892" },
  { "_id": "57760f56f5e7478c1e46b896" },
  { "_id": "57760f7df5e7478c1e46b89a" } ]
```

to this

```
"_id" : [ "57760ecef5e7478c1e46b892", "57760f56f5e7478c1e46b896", "57760f7df5e7478c1e46b89a" ]
```

through code.

I am relatively new to the world of node.js so I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the arrow functions of ES6 to do that in a very concise way:

```
var obj = {_id: yourArray.map((item) => item._id)}
```

See [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrr = [{
  "_id": "57760ecef5e7478c1e46b892"
}, {
  "_id": "57760f56f5e7478c1e46b896"
}, {
  "_id": "57760f7df5e7478c1e46b89a"
}]

var newObj = {
  "_id": arrr.map(function(elem) {
    return elem["_id"];
  })
};
console.log(newObj);
```